# I want a Ducky One 2 TKL Keyboard for Office use. But which Cherry MX switches should I buy?

Tags: keyboards

As mentioned above already, I want to buy a Ducky One 2 TKL RGB keyboard to use in the office. I am a software developer and type fast and I press the buttons quiet hard.

Which Cherry MX switches would you recommend for office use ? It should be not to noisy.

I also like the clicky sound, is there a switch that is clicky and not noisy ?

Bests

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/366797/317198 for a quick and easy breakdown of the most common MX Cherry switches. Personally, I use blues at home (clicky) and clears at work (firm, quiet with tactile feedback). I would also recommend getting O-rings to put on the bottom of the keys, as they help with the "clack".

Comment: I personally have a ducky one with red switches. I first wanted to bring my cherry mx  blues to work, but after 10 minutes of typing on it collegues came to ask why I was making so much noise typing. I think it is best to avoid clicky switches, to preserve the peace at work :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a breakdown of all of the genuine Cherry MX switches in [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_(keyboards)#Cherry_MX_switches_in_consumer_keyboards).

The MX Blue switches are very common and make the distinct clicking noise as you type. It is up to personal opinion whether the noise is too loud; I would be annoyed if the person beside me used a keyboard with MX Blue switches all day.

The MX White and MX Green are variations of the MX Blue that require more force. These  are probably harder to find in stock at a local retailer because they don't seem to be as popular.

If you want the same tactile feedback as MX Blue without the clicking noise you should go for MX Brown.

Likewise for MX Blue, there are also Clear and Gray switches which require more force.

There are also several other brands of mechanical switches which could offer something in the sweet spot between MX Blue and MX Brown, but your question asks for Cherry MX switches only.